# register form in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I'm new in Yii 1 framework!
I built register form in this framework with controller , model and view.
my controller like this:

```
<?php class RegisterController extends Controller{
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->layout='//layouts/main';
    $this->render('index');
}  public function actionRegister() {
$model   = new RegisterForm ;
$newUser = new User;   if(isset($_POST['RegisterForm'])) {
  $model->attributes = $_POST['RegisterForm'];
  if($model->validate()) {
  $newUser->name = $model->name ;
  $newUser->contact_no = $model->contact_no;
  $newUser->email = $model->email;
  $newUser->password = $model->password;
  if($newUser->save()) {
   $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($newUser->email,$newUser->password);
    if($this->_identity->authenticate())
     Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity);
     $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
    }
  }
}$this->render('register',array('model'=>$model));}}
```

and i have also a view file named  register and it has two php file named index and register
but when i entered my addrees : http://localhost/blog/index.php/register
its just show what in index file but i want to see what i set in register file but i don't know how can i do that
can anybody help me?

and here are my index and register codes on view file:(register)

```
   <?php echo CHtml::errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'Name'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'name') ?>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'Contact Number'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'contact_no') ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'email') ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activePasswordField($model,'password') ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'Retype Password'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activePasswordField($model,'retypepassword') ?>
</div>

<div class="row submit">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Register'); ?>
</div>

<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

index:

```
<?php $this->breadcrumbs=array(
'Register',);?> <p>
You may change the content of this page by modifying
the file <tt><?php echo __FILE__; ?></tt>.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

first when you new to Yii i recommend you to use Yii 2.

Now your Problem. It´s show you use the wrong url.

You have the `RegisterController` and the Route from this Controller
are `http://localhost/blog/index.php/register` or `http://localhost/blog/index.php?r=register` and `http://localhost/blog/index.php/register/index` or `http://localhost/blog/index.php?r=register/index` are the same.

This was the default and call the `actionIndex` function.

For call the `actionRegister` function. You must call this URL `http://localhost/blog/index.php/register/register` or `http://localhost/blog/index.php?r=register/register`

Here you can find the Doc about Controller Routing:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#route

When you want to use `http://localhost/blog/register` you must enable the `urlManager` https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing wrong way, i think issue is related to routing. Try using below url

http://localhost/blog/index.php?r=register for access